# Sampling the confluent hypergeometric function kind one distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling

The *confuent hypergeometric function kind one distribution* 
$CH(\nu,a,b)$ has density function at $x \geqslant 0$ given by
$$
\frac{\Gamma(b-\nu)}{B(a-\nu,\nu)\Gamma(b)}x^{\nu-1}
{}_1\!F_1(a, b; -x)
$$
for $\underline{\nu > 0}$, $\underline{a > \nu}$, $\underline{b > \nu}$.

It is related to the *Gamma-Beta distribution* 
$\mathcal{G}\mathcal{B}(\nu, \alpha, \beta)$, which is the distribution 
of a random variable $X$ such that
$$
(X \mid U=u) \sim \mathcal{G}(\nu, u), 
\quad U \sim \mathcal{B}(\alpha,\beta),
$$
where the second parameter of the Gamma distribution $\mathcal{G}$ is 
its *rate* parameter, not the *scale* parameter.

Equivalently, the $\mathcal{G}{B}(\nu,\alpha,\beta)$ distribution is 
the distribution of the quotient $Y/U$ where 
$Y \sim \mathcal{G}(\nu,1)$ is independent of 
$U \sim \mathcal{B}(\alpha,\beta)$.

The relation between $CH$ and $\mathcal{G}{B}$ is
$$
\boxed{CH(\nu, a, b) = \mathcal{G}{B}(\nu, a-\nu, b-a)}
$$
under the parameter constraints $\nu>0$, $a>\nu$, $\underline{b > a}$, because $\mathcal{G}{B}(\nu, \alpha, \beta)$ is defined for $\beta>0$ only.

So we have an easy way to simulate $CH(\nu, a, b)$ when $\boxed{b>a}$. 
My question is: how to simulate this distribution under the general 
constraint $b > \nu$, allowing $b \leqslant a$?